# Add panels dynamically to form

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, controls, panel

I'm trying to add panels to a form according to the ids quantity that is received. At running, the panels are added to the form, but only the first one has the controls, and I don't get why.

This is my actual code:

```
private void loadItems(List<int> ids)
{
    int id = 0,
        panelX = 10,
        panelY = -30,
        itemslblX = 15,
        itemslblY = -65,
        IDtxtX = 360,
        IDtxtY = -40,
        nametxtX = 130,
        nametxtY = -40;

    int height = (80 * ids.Count) + 50;
    this.Size = new Size(600,height);

    foreach(int c in ids)
    {
        panelY = panelY + 80;
        itemslblY = itemslblY + 80;
        terrainMenuY = terrainMenuY + 80;
        IDtxtY = IDtxtY + 80;
        nametxtY = nametxtY + 80;

        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.Location = new Point(panelX, panelY);
        panel.Dock = DockStyle.None;
        panel.Height = 75;
        panel.Width = 575;
        panel.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        panel.Name = ids[id]+"Panel".ToString();

        Label itemslbl = new Label();
        itemslbl.Location = new Point(itemslblX, itemslblY);
        itemslbl.Text = "Imagen            Nombre                                         ID";
        itemslbl.Height = 20;
        itemslbl.Width = 550;
        itemslbl.Name = ids[id] + "itemsLabel".ToString();

        TextBox IDtxt = new TextBox();
        IDtxt.Location = new Point(IDtxtX, IDtxtY);
        IDtxt.Height = 27;
        IDtxt.Width = 200;
        IDtxt.Text = ids[id].ToString();
        IDtxt.ReadOnly = true;
        IDtxt.Name = ids[id] + "IDtext".ToString();

        TextBox nametxt = new TextBox();
        nametxt.Location = new Point(nametxtX, nametxtY);
        nametxt.Height = 27;
        nametxt.Width = 200;
        nametxt.ReadOnly = true;
        nametxt.Name = ids[id] + "nameText".ToString();

        panel.Controls.Add(itemslbl);
        panel.Controls.Add(nametxt);
        panel.Controls.Add(IDtxt);

        this.Controls.Add(panel);
        id++;
    }
}
```

[image: Here's how it seems]

Any advice, please, and thanks for your time.

Comment: On the first glance it looks like you should change the positions/locations of your inner controls in the loop, or take a different panel, like [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: The TableLayoutPanel did loaded the controls, thanks a lot. Now I just need to organize them.

Comment: glad to hear. my guess was that you simply put the new controls for each id over the old ones and this is why you get the impression that they are not there, because you cannot see them. good fortune to get them organized :) If you would have used the `int c` in your code, like writing it into the id textbox, you may be would have realized that you only see the last id

Comment: For automatic layout insert a FlowLayoutPanel!

Comment: You could also opt to make a UserControl that contains the labels and text boxes, and then add several instances of the UserControl into the Panel container.